# Laravel artisan tinker from Amazon Linux 2 (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tinker

I used to execute `tinker` on previous Amazon AMI by using this command :

```
sudo -E -u webapp php artisan tinker
```

Now I am using `PHP 7.4 on Amazon Linux 2` and when I execute the above command, I get this error :

```
Unable to create PsySH runtime directory. Make sure PHP is able to write to /run/user/1000 in order to continue.
```

So, In order to test, I gave the full permission to this folder and then executed my command again :

```
sudo chmod 777 /run/user/1000
sudo -E -u webapp php artisan tinker
```

Actually, no error, but the environnement variables such as `RDS_PASSWORD` or `RDS_DB_NAME` are not loaded, making it impossible to perform database actions :

```
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> env('RDS_DB_NAME')
 => null
>>> User::first()
 Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 
 (SQL: select * from `users` limit 1)'
```

I also tried to `echo` the variable from a shell, I got the same result :

```
sudo su webapp
sh-4.2$ echo $RDS_DB_NAME
  # Empty here
```

Comment: Where do you have those environment variables set up?

Comment: Because it is an EB environment, there are automatically provided by AWS to the server instances, there is no need to set them up manually.

Comment: Some information here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html#php-rds-connect
I use Laravel, so I access them using `env('RDS_XXX')` instead of `$_SERVER` but that's quite similar.

Comment: @Marc I am also facing this same problem and I can not find what the issue is. Please let me know if you found a fix for it.

Comment: @realnsleo That's why I put a bounty on this. I looked all over the internet and didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's **not on the documentation** but the environment variables are in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`

So you can do something like this:

```
export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env) && sudo -E -u webapp php artisan tinker
```

Also, to deal with the `PsySH` problem, just create a `.psysh.php` file in your source code directory with that content:

```
<?php

return [
    'runtimeDir'    => './.psysh',
];
```

Psysh will then use that directory without any permission problem because `webapp` owns it.

Comment: Thank you Claire! I have come across an issue however, the above does not escape values that are stored in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` that contain spaces and as such, my commands are using different environment variables to my application. Any suggestions on how one can fix this?